# One of my UICollectionViews is not scrolling or responding to touch events inside my UIScrollView container [Puzzling]

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I have an unusual and challenging problem. I have researched deeply on StackOverflow and have been unable to find any solutions. Please do not ask about my design style- it must be this way.

I have a UIPageViewController that contains a UIScrollView which contains 4 UICollectionViews. Each of these collection views should be horizontally scrollable but not vertically scrollable. The scroll view is necessary because the screen is not large enough to display all 4 collection views. Upon loading the screen, the 4th collection view is not immediately visible. After scrolling down, the 4th collection view then becomes visible.

The problem I am having is the 4th collection view does not respond to touches. Specifically, it does not respond to taps or attempts to scroll. The other 3 work perfectly fine. What makes this puzzling and odd is that the 4th one is exactly the same as the other 3, the delegate and data source are set properly and user interaction is enabled. The only real difference between the problematic collection view and the others is that it is not immediately visible when the screen loads.

When I attempt to scroll it behaves as if I am trying to change the page, so the UIPageView changes the page. So the CollectionView isn't registering any touches at all. I have a hunch that it either has to do with the GestureRecognizer from the PageView or something to do with how it isn't visible on the screen upon the initial load.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check if some other transparent element is overlapping with it. 
Share screen/video for the same

Comment: can you please add the code chunks? without code its tough to find out the issue. By your well laid explanation it seems the issue might be with the contentSIze of the scrollView but need to see the code to know more.

Comment: @Satish It turned out to be not an overlap, but the opposite. My collection view was outside of the container view for my scroll view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% sure without seeing the initialization of code or storyboard, but the best thing is that maybe there is a view overlapping. You can run your program and click on the 2 overlapping rectangles. This is the `Debug View Hierarchy`. It shows you your current frame on your phone and you can see the view laid out in hierarchal status.

[image]

Comment: This led to me solving my problem, thank you. Posted an explanation for it as an answer.

Comment: At least upvote so others who experience this can see how to use this tool. Cheers

Comment: Yes, @Xayhem you should upvote and can accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: @Satish I did upvote but it won't show due to my low rank

Answer (score 2):

Solved my own problem thanks to [impression7vx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5009432/impression7vx)'s mention of the `Debug View Hierarchy`. Had no clue this existed but it let me discover the flaw. I am just writing this to help people who stumble upon this in the future.

I had a content view inside the ScrollView that had a problematic constraint. I set it to have "Equal Heights" with the ScrollView but upon loading the screen the height was static. Only half of the scroll view showed and that half would be registered as the height for the UIView. Since it was static the view would not become larger when I'd scroll, and the 4th collection view would not be inside that container view anymore. For some reason, since the collection view wasn't in the container view it wouldn't register touches.

Solved by manually making the height the same value of the scroll view! This allowed the content view to contain all of the collection views which made them behave normally again.

Answer (score 0):

Just take **NSLayoutConstraint** of height of the **UIView** inside the **UIScrollView**

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollContentViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Set height of this scrollContentViewHeight equal to height of dynamic size of the UIScrollView

```
if scrollableView.contentSize.height = 840.0
then 
scrollContentViewHeight.constant = 840.0
```

set it on **viewDidLayoutSubviews**

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
 
        scrollableView.contentSize.height = 840.0
        scrollContentViewHeight.constant = 840.0

    }
```